# responsive menu position css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We have extracted the responsive menu from this site

http://mattkersley.com/demos/responsive_menu/

When i resize the screen size the menu select box displayed at the top of the page default. 
I found the below code causes the issue. But if i change this the responsive menu didn't work.

```
var settings = {
combine: true, //combine multiple menus into a single select
groupPageText: 'Main', //optgroup's aren't selectable, make an option for it
nested: true, //create optgroups by default
prependTo: 'body', //insert at top of page by default
switchWidth: 650, //width at which to switch to select, and back again
topOptionText: 'Select a page' //default "unselected" state
}
```

How to change the position of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by changing the attribute in "prependTo: 'body'". We need to provide the html tag like nav, p, div to display the navigation in that location.